# AttributeError: module 'QuantLib' has no attribute 'date'

Tags: date, module, attributes, attributeerror, quantlib

I use Anaconda and jupyter notebook.
I installed Quantlib in an environment.

I run the following piece of code and get an AttributeError

```py
import QuantLib as ql

calculation_date = ql.date(9,1,2008)
ql.Settings.instance().evaluationDate = calculation_date
```

The following error:

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-3ded7a4b7cb5> in <module>()
----> 1 calculation_date = ql.date(9,1,2004)
      2 ql.Settings.instance().evaluationDate = calculation_date

AttributeError: module 'QuantLib' has no attribute 'date'
```

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I think it requieres caps? You should use **`Date`** instead of `date`

```
import QuantLib as ql
calculation_date = ql.Date(9,1,2008)
ql.Settings.instance().evaluationDate = calculation_date
```

Comment: Fixed it. I swear I had tried it before without succes. Anyways, thanks!